# Replace a word in a string using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried using replaceAll and replaceWith and they don't seem to work

for example, string

`"~/Foo.aspx?fn=/image.jpg&p=True"`

I want to do is replace `p=True` with `p=False`

```
var previewSource = "~/Foo.aspx?fn/image.jpg&p=True"
var loadedSource = $(previewSource).replaceAll("p=True").replaceWith("p=False");// This is one of the things I have tried.
```

Comment: How about previewSource.replace(/p=true/i, 'p=False');

Comment: @LShetty, good idea but I would also add quotes to force it as a string. I don't know if OP made a typo or not "~Foo.aspx?fn/image.jpg&p=True"

Comment: @Grimbode, good catch! not sure if it was a mistake. I've added it in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pure Javscript here:

```
var previewSource = '~Foo.aspx?fn/image.jpg&p=True';
var loadedSource = previewSource.replace("p=True", "p=False");
```

Comment: Ah, somehow this is something I overlooked. That is exactly what I was after. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var previewSource = "~Foo.aspx?fn/image.jpg&p=True";
var loadedSource = previewSource.replace(/p=true/i, 'p=False'); // This is one of the things I have tried.
```

P.S.

Since the value of previewSource is string, you need to wrap them in quotes. Then use simple javascript to replace.

Comment: /p=true/i a typo? Should be True instead of true, since we don't test for lower/upper case

Comment: @Grimbode, no, it's the regex pattern to match True or true.

Comment: Ok, then pretend I didn't say anything. ;)